# How to enable Firefox back/forward action on horizontal scrolling like Safari?

Tags: firefox

In Safari browser (on Mac OSX) when using the magic mouse and swipping up/down, the web page scrolls up/down as with every normal mouse using the mouse weel. But when swipping the finger left/right quickly, this translates to back/forward gesture and the web page changes accordingly. Is this behaviour possible on Firefox?

If this is operating system specific I would prefer an Ubuntu solution. Thanks.

Comment: Could you edit your question with a better description so that those of us who don't use Safari can understand what you want.

Answer (score 2):

on mine if enabled by default... 
anyway, go to `about:config`, look for the following lines,  and set them as so:

`browser.gesture.swipe.left to string: Browser:BackOrBackDuplicate` and `browser.gesture.swipe.right to string: Browser:ForwardOrForwardDuplicate`

Comment: These lines are the same with mine. Can you go to the previous page by scrolling left on your touchpad or magic mouse?